# How to not print the output if the second pattern does not match

Tags: awk, sed, pattern-matching

file1:

```
pattern1
a
b
c
end
```

cmd=>

```
cat file1 | sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p'
```

output=>

```
pattern1
a
b
c
end
```

How to not print the output if the second pattern does not match?

Desired output:

```
pattern1
```

Comment: Which second pattern?

Comment: You don't need to pipe `cat` into `sed`. The latter can be used with the filename as an argument. As far as just print `pattern1` from the file, that can be done with either the command that Kamil gave or with `grep pattern1 filename.txt`. As previously stated, the command that you have will give a syntax error.

Comment: It would be good if you could describe what the file can and cannot contain.  For example, can there be multiple `pattern1`-`pattern2` pairs?  Can there be a `pattern2` (or more than one) but no `pattern1`?  Can there be `pattern1`-`pattern1`-`pattern2` or `pattern1`-`pattern2`-`pattern2`?  If you can rule out some combinations, more solutions might become possible. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2):

You need to buffer the text until you see the end "pattern" (horrible word btw - see [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern)), e.g. see the awk commands below:

```
$ cat file1
pattern1
a
b
c
end
```

```
$ sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' file1
pattern1
a
b
c
end
```

```
$ awk '/pattern1/{f=1; print; buf=""; next} f{buf=buf $0 ORS; if (/pattern2/) {printf "%s", buf; f=0} }' file1
pattern1
```

```
$ awk '/pattern1/{f=1; print; buf=""; next} f{buf=buf $0 ORS; if (/end/) {printf "%s", buf; f=0} }' file1
pattern1
a
b
c
end
```